# Chronological list of improvements in number of logical qubits

Tags: resource-request

Was wondering if anyone has any historical data/charts showing the number of over logical qubits over time. I am hoping to include something illustrative of Moore's law as applied to quantum computing for a presentation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if such a chart *already* exists, but I'd refer you to the [Timeline of quantum computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_quantum_computing) on Wikipedia and the citations therein. It is quite comprehensive and you can extract the "number of qubits vs. time" data from there and create your own charts.

There's also [this](https://sciencenode.org/feature/3-reasons-why-quantum-computing-is-closer-than-ever.php) but it misses out on a lot of details (and is a bit misleading):

[image]

Nevertheless, I'd like to mention that the number of qubits by itself is not a good measure of the performance of quantum computers. And Moore's law is not really applicable to quantum computing. Please read through the following threads.

- [Is Google's 72 qubit device better than D-Wave's machines, which feature more than 2000 qubits?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1428)
- [How should different quantum computing devices be compared?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1255)
- [Does Moore's law apply to quantum computing?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1803)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you the [Quantum Computing Report](https://quantumcomputingreport.com/our-take/applying-moores-law-to-quantum-qubits/) page, where several news about quantum computing and other interesting data about the quantity of qubits and quality of them in each existing nowadays is presented. The link I added refers to a post called "Applying Moore's law to quantum qubits" as you are specifically requiring such information.